# I'm designing a python api to play a singleplayer game. should I use statemachine with different states?

Tags: design, python

I'm designing a python api to play a singleplayer card collection game and my prototype includes a state machine which uses pyautogui's locate function to recognize and update current game state through clicking the game directly. I am planning to use statemachine packet from pypi. Ideally this Api would be hooked up to a Neural network.

After reading  [WHY DEVELOPERS NEVER USE STATE MACHINES](https://workflowengine.io/blog/why-developers-never-use-state-machines/), I got worried if an overcomplicated STATE MACHINES will be ton of a hassle to maintain since my statemachine starts with 40 is states and most of them needs to be interconnected through function, and if all of the States requires specific functions to move from each other, it would be over couples of hundred functions for each action. Is there a way to avoid this specific problem? Am I even looking in the correct direction? If Statemachines are horrible, what are some alternatives to using statemachines?

```
class CS(StateMachine):
    home = State(
    dock = State(
    supply = State(
    refit = State(
    bathtub = State(
    factory = State(

    sortiePage1 = State(u
    sortiePage2 = State(u
    sortiePage3 = State(u
    sortiePage4 = State(u
    sortiePage5 = State(u
    sortiePage6 = State(u
    sortiePage7 = State(u
    expeditionPage1 = State(u
    expeditionPage2 = State(u
    expeditionPage3 = State(u
    expeditionPage4 = State(u
    expeditionPage5 = State(u
    expeditionPage6 = State(u
    expeditionPage7 = State(u
```

Comment: Regarding your linked article - "never" rarely applies in this field, there are always exceptions to every rule. Some situations state machines are appropriate and developers do use them.

Comment: Not saying yours is appropriate though, you'll have to make that determination yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"consider possible alternatives [to writing your own state machine]" says the people selling a drag and drop state machine building tool.

They say that's because one might need to think the about all the possible user flows that might happen, the code may need to change if things change (a lot of code if the design is poor or the change is big) and it might get complex. All of these criticisms are true, but at the same time they're complete trash. That's because they're true of any attempt to divide code to manage complexity.

Don't worry about it, write a state machine.
Here's [a better article](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state) about how to make a good one.